# When writing TypeScript in WebStorm, is there an Action to insert a lambda to match the signature of the current argument?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

When writing promise chains in TypeScript, there's a bit of a syntax tax, and I'd like to automate that away if possible. I'm using WebStorm, and ideally I'd like an Action that I can call to insert a lambda with the signature of the argument displayed in the Parameter Info popup.

e.g., if I'm trying to detect the presence of an item in a list, and I'm writing the following code:
[image]
I'd like to register a shortcut to insert

```
(value, index, array) => {
}
```

at the cursor.

Does any action like this currently exist?

Comment: I'm guessing you already know about Live Templates - you could create one for each of your use-cases. I'm not sure if there's anything that follows argument signatures in TS...

Comment: [Well, it seems to work out of the box with Ctrl+Space.](https://imgur.com/a/rOw13ns) (I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate, but I doubt this is an Ultimate-only feature.)

Comment: @chazsolo yeah, the live templates don't give you access to type signature information, so can't be used (AFAICT) to generate lambdas dynamically if you don't know the signature and configure a live template for it explicitly ahead of time.

Comment: @Jeto can you look in your keymap to see the name of the action associated with Ctrl+space in your IDE? I want to see if that exists in WebStorm.

Comment: `Main menu` > `Code` > `Completion` > `Basic`. What does it show for you?

Comment: Pretty much every type name available, and a whole bunch of functions I could call -- but it doesn't look like it's offering to define a new lambda for me. Lemme configure a TypeScript project in IntelliJ Ultimate instead and compare.

Comment: Hmm, IntelliJ Ultimate behaves the same as WebStorm for me. Lemme see if I just have some intentions turned off maybe?

Comment: @Dathan Try explicit-typing your value, like this: `.then((logs: any[]) => { logs.some(...) })` (replace `any` with the actual item type if you can)

Comment: Huh. If I erase all the cruft after it, it apparently enabled WebStorm to do better type inference, and Ctrl+Space gave me the popup you posted. Weird that it didn't do it earlier. I'll have to play around with it a little bit - but otherwise that's pretty much exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just hit `Ctrl+Space` within parenthesis and choose the signature from completion list:

[image]